# how to find this update will impact my org securely access aura components (update) winter 22?

Tags: update, release

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_aura_security_ru.htm&type=5&release=232

I was not able to get the context,How it is going to effect my org ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be applicable only if you have a managed package that has an aura component and you use that component in your custom aura component. Otherwise, this will have no effect on you.

Things you should look for is below,

Let's say you have a Managed Package app with namespace `xyx`, then look for something like this in your custom component markup,

```
<aura:component>
 <xyz:managedPackageComponent att1="attribute1val" att2="attribute2val"/>
```

Or something like below

```
$A.createComponent(
        "xyz:myComponent",
        {
            "att1": "attribute1val",
            "att2": "attribute2val"
        },
```

In the above, if `att1` and `att2` come from a Managed Package app they need to be declared as `global` for your custom component to consume. If they are declared `public` they will fail with error `the access check fails`. At that point, you should reach to the package vendor to get it fixed.

If you own a Managed package app and you provide custom aura components for your customers to use them in their code, you will need to make sure you provide `global` access to attributes you aim to expose to subscriber orgs for consumption

On the other hand, take the access of attributes down from `global` to `public` if you do not plan to expose the attributes to subscriber org.

Comment: If i have $A.getCallback() call back in js files then this components are going to effect. My question here is all the js files which having this callback irrespective of component access global or public access should i consider them ?

Comment: No it's not going to effect if you have $A.getCallback(), it will only affect if you are dynamically creating components with namespace

Comment: @RajkumarA1 Added more explanation so you understand it better.

Comment: I would be rather surprised if it is possible to demote an existing attribute from global to public in a managed package, and would ask you to confirm whether this really is going to be possible le (it runs counter to normal managed package globals handling).

Comment: @phil W I will check this one to see if this is possible and update it.